# What can I say to show that I'm skeptical and haughty?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, argentina

The scenario: I've been in the same city as my girlfriend for a grand total of three weeks in the last three years.  Most of the time apart we can't even call or text but have to use email.  Other people then tell me that their long distance relationships are hard because they have to be away for a month or two with more communication privileges than me.

"Cuando escucho a tales personas, _________ ."

What can I say here to express how ridiculous and petty their long distance struggles are compared to mine?  I'm looking for something in the form of "me da _____" or "siento con ______" for example.  Bonus points if the answer is/involves an expression used in the Córdoba, Argentina area.

Comment: Podrías simplemente expresarlo diciendo: tu relación me da envidia, si tan solo supieras lo mucho mas difícil que es o ah sido en mi caso ... _(saludos desde Buenos Aires)_

Comment: "me dudo tales personas .." is a matter of fact way. yuo want a phrase you can inject to the end though..

Comment: A common expression in any Spanish speaking country is "no tener de qué quejarse" or "ser un exagerado". Also, maybe @Marco can confirm, but I think "quejoso" could be a close synonym for a moaner/whiner in Rioplatense Spanish. You could say "Cuando escucho a tales personas lamentarse de lo que les cuesta mantener sus relaciones a distancia, me parecen todos unos quejosos. La verdad es que no tienen de qué quejarse, son unos exagerados."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical expression is

> Cuando escucho a tales personas siento que **se quejan de llenos**.

It means they are unhappy with their situation even though it's much better than that experienced by others.

Comment: You may want to specify where this expression is used. In Spain, most people wouldn't probably understand what it means (I, for one, had never heard of it until now).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

""Cuando escucho a tales personas, me da risa ."

"When I hear people say something like that, it makes me laugh"